# Information Retrieval - Top K Documents given list of queries/words

Tags: information-retrieval

I came across this problem of retrieving top k documents given a list of documents and queries but can’t seem to think of a good solution. Can anyone share their thoughts/suggestions?
The problem is given a list of documents and queries where each query is a word like “Software”, return the top k documents for each of the queries.

I thought of

- creating a hash map of word to a set of documents and for each of the queries
- build a map between query and map of the document name and count how many times query occurs in a document
- Finally for each query use the priority queue to yield the top k documents that have the highest count.
  I feel like this could be done in a better way and would appreciate it if you could share your thoughts.
  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on this problem too and I can share some ideas.

First, reading your 3 propositions, I'm wondering, do you have a fix set of queries that can be asked ? Or do you need to be able to handle any query an user could make, with potentially OOV words ?
Also, it's important to give more metadata. How many documents do you have ?

For now I suggest that you try Okapi bm25, it's a ranking function based on Term Frequency and Inverse Document Frequency.
Here is a tutorial to know more about it: [Creating a robust full text search in Python](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-build-a-search-engine-9f8ffa405eac).
It could help you even if you don't develop in Python.